# arrow style css button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a big arrow back button but the arrow seems off center. Can anyone tell me how to clean this up and get it looking right?

```
#buttonboxback {
    left:20px;/*change the position*/
    top:10px;/*change the position*/
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color: #003366;/*change this and the background color for the :before element*/
        width:162px;
    height:56px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 8px;
    z-index : 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius : 10px 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius : 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow :-1px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)inset,
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8)inset;
    font-size : 11px;
    display : block;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow : 0px -1px 0px #000;
    line-height : 30px;
    font-family : HelveticaNeue;
    font-weight: 700;
    -webkit-background-size : 30px;
}
#buttonboxback:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:9.9%;
    left:-15px;
    -webkit-background-size : 22px 22px;
    background-position :-2px -1.5px;
    background-color: #003366;
    height : 45px;
    width: 60px;
    -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg) skew(-10deg, -10deg);
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius : 100px 40px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius : 30px 2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius : 2px 30px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius : 40px 100px;
    z-index : 1;
    content : ' ';
    border-left : 1.5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow :  1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset,
        -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;
    -webkit-mask-image :
        -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
            from(#000000),
            color-stop(0.33,#000000),
            color-stop(0.5, transparent),
            to(transparent));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RHXS/

Thanks!

UPDATE: I adjusted the code and also added a hover but the hover does not work correctly..

http://jsfiddle.net/9RHXS/2/

Comment: I don't see any arrow in the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution using borders, pseudo-classes, and absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/9RHXS/5/.

EDITED VERSION: introduced hovering effect

HTML:

```
<div id="buttonboxback"><a href="index.php">BACK</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttonboxback {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#buttonboxback:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -17px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 20px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent darkblue transparent transparent;
}

#buttonboxback > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 18px/40px Sans-Serif;
}

#buttonboxback:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#buttonboxback:hover:before {
    border-right-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: this works best I think. Is there anyway to do a hover on this with the arrow part changing at the same time??

Comment: Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/9RHXS/5/

Comment: i prefer this solution...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrow's head is having a position of absolute. Which means it would be rendered by the relative element of it, to position where we want it to be. Your element right now, has the top property set as `9.9%`. Which is a huge value for it. Changed the `top` property of the arrow `:before` and now it works.

Change it to

```
top: 3%;
```

It works now. And it is aligned just where it should be.

Have a look now: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/9RHXS/1/

Comment: That works well. I moved the arrow over a little more left. But is there any way to straight up the lines which make the arrow itself? They are currently slight curved right now. Just curious if you might know?

Comment: @user3537376, I am sorry, but I got no idea about that one. :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your `top` value for the `#buttonboxback:before` element to `0`.

```
#buttonboxback:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RHXS/2/